# Laravel - Accessing session value from an iframe

Tags: php, laravel, session-variables

Good morning.
I have a whole site made with Laravel 6, and I need to embed a third party piece of code, not made with Laravel.

The only thing I need from Laravel is the user privileges, but I see that I cannot read the session from the Iframe.

My Laravel session is stored in a file...

```
**config/session.php**
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

Reading the docs, I see that I can also use cookies to store sessions, but they will be encrypted, so... same problem, I believe.

The page inside the Iframe is part of the site (by now is inside /public directory) and can of course read its data.

Any possibile way to read the session?

**EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I'm using Sentinel to manage the user login session**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if your "laravel page" and "iframe page" run on the same domain, then it shouldn't be a problem to share the session via cookies, that's the way in my opinion

Comment: @MartinOsusky The problem is that even if I set "cookie" as session driver, I have just a <myapp>_session cookie to read, with nothing really readable inside.